# Intuition behind the definition of the d'Alembert operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The d'Alembert operator is defined as $$\square^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}-\nabla^{2}$$
My question is what is the intuition behind this definition? My intuition tells me that we should Instead define such operator like a $$\square^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}+\nabla^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}}$$
Because then we would have space derivatives (Laplace operator) + time derivatives. But with d'Alembert definition we have time derivative - space derivative. Why?

Comment: It's because of Minkowski metric, and for this particular choice of metric see for example: [What is the exact motivation for the Minkowski metric?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557381/what-is-the-exact-motivation-for-the-minkowski-metric/1095554)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\nabla^2 \phi = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} \phi$$
is up to scaling the wave-equation. So solving it is equivalent to find members of the kernel of the d'Alembert operator. Thinking about solving PDEs this way is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The ultimate reason the d'Alembertian is useful is that the metric of spacetime is (+,-,-,-); that is, the invariant interval along a path is $\int (dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2)$.
Given that metric, the natural extension to space time of
$$
\delta_{ii} \partial_i \partial_i
$$
is 
$$
g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \partial_\nu
$$
which is (up to a sign) the d'Alembertian.

The interesting thing is that he came up with this before Minkowski space was a common concept.